# Detail:HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Error: name expected at the position 20 of 'struct<email:string, name:string>' but ' ' is found

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I have cloudformation template:

```
AuditTable:
Type: AWS::Glue::Table
Properties:
  CatalogId: !Ref AWS::<SomeRef>
  DatabaseName: !Ref <someref>
  TableInput:
    Name: !Sub audit_logs_by_email
    TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
    StorageDescriptor:
      Location:
        Fn::Sub:
          - s3://${LogsBucket}/
          - LogsBucket: !ImportValue audit:logs:s3:bucket
      InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
      OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
      SerdeInfo:
        SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
        Parameters: {
          "serialization.format": 1
        }
      Columns:
        - Name: id
          Type: int
        - Name: field2
          Type: array<int>
        - Name: field3
          Type: string
        - Name: field4
          Type: string
        - Name: field5
          Type: string
        - Name: metadata
          Type: struct<email:string, name:string>
```

But when I do a select:

```
select * from audit_logs_by_email limit 1
```

I got this error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):
[ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:QUERY_FAILED], Detail:HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Error: name expected at the position 20 of 'struct<email:string, ip:string>' but ' ' is found. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

When I run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE audit_logs_by_email;
```

I got

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: name expected at the position 56 of 'int:array<int>:string:string:string:struct<email:string, ip:string>' but ' ' is found.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the space inside of

```
Type: struct<email:string, name:string>
```

should be:

```
Type: struct<email:string,name:string>
```